# CPU reaching 98C when using Google Hangouts

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, overheating, elementaryos

When idling my laptop is 45 - 50C, when browsing it is 55 - 70C and when watching HD videos it is 75 - 87 and when doing a hangouts call (with HD on my webcam) it is 93 - 98C. The laptop is very loud and hot to touch (boil water on it :).

I assembled this laptop from scratch recently (2 months) and applied thermal paste and cleaned the fan.

The laptop is a HP Pavilion g7 2269wm running elementary OS (Windows gives me over 150C which is wrong ?).

The room temperature is 30C - 35C normally and 23 - 30C when raining. When it is raining the laptop goes up to 95C.

Any suggestions.

It is raining very hard as I type this and the temperature is 56C.

I have an older laptop with 1.4 GHZ and it only goes up to 75C. This laptop can boost up to 2.8GHZ so it creates more heat.

I am using the FGLRX driver

Comment: Are you sure that the fan is running? 150°C while running windows is not an expected result with a fan.

Comment: I would double check the thermal paste on it. Otherwise it is very hard to tell what is wrong because it could be a hardware problem.

Comment: Laptop works perfectly. Never BSODed / kernel panicked. Only problem is overheating

Comment: Could it be the high room temperature ?

Comment: Perhaps. I get ~55°C with my HP laptop when the room is ~25°C.

Comment: @TheKB 55C when doing what

Comment: Currently it is not raining and it is evening. The room temperature is 28C and the laptop is 59 - 64C when typing this.

Comment: @TheKB Even NeverBall heats the laptop up to 94C after about a minute of gameplay

Comment: Have you tried running something like [SpeedFan](http://almico.com/speedfan.php) to monitor the fan speed and try to increase it.

Comment: @TheKB Software like SpeedFan doesn't work on HP laptops

Comment: @TheKB When I play NeverBall with max settings (changed in the AMD Catalyst Control Center) in about 30 seconds the temperature goes from 65C to 96 - 98C.I still get high frame rates (55 - 60) but I stop playing NeverBall to prevent damage to my CPU.For some reason it does not heat up on battery (which only lasts for 30 minutes) although it has low frame rates (due to throttling).

Comment: @TheKB Windows is known to give wrong temperatures on Trinity APUs.I accidently deleted my old comment so I have to write it again

Comment: So reapplied thermal paste.Now when compiling code with 4 threads (something which previously heated it up-to 98+C and it would throttle) would make it go up-to 93C , then the fan speeds up and the temperature goes down to 85C -  88C and stays there.


Problem solved. The room temperature when doing this was about 30 - 33C.When typing this the room temperature is 29C and I have 10 Chrome tabs open , Android Studio and the temperature is only 55C

Comment: @TheKB I ran Prime95 + Furmark and the temperature goes up-to **91 °C** (and the laptop draws **50** watts) which is something **no game / program would ever do** ;) .Running Prime95 without Furmark gives me temperatures of about **86 - 88 °C**.Tried Neverball and the temperature is about **74 - 80 °C** with VSync off and **47 - 55 °C** with VSync **ON**